# Search for a sequence of additions which value is closest to the target value

Tags: python, c#, recursion

I have a certain target value which is a double.
Now given this array of doubles:

```
data = [0.41, 0.96, 1.91, 2.9]
```

I want to find a sequence of additions which value is closest to the target and print it out.

Here is the example how the sequence could look like if the

> target value= 11.0

This is how closest addition sequence to the target value can look like.

> 0.41 + 1.91 + 2.90 + 2.90 + 2.90 = 11.02

Answer (score 1):

You could check all possible combinations with replacement of `data`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from math import ceil

result = min(
    (abs(target - sum(c)), c)
    for n in range(1, ceil(target / min(data)) + 1)
    for c in combinations_with_replacement(data, n)
)[1]
```

Result (with `data = [0.41, 0.96, 1.91, 2.9]` and `target = 11`):

```
>>> result
(0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.96, 0.96, 2.9, 2.9)
>>> sum(result)
11.0
```

Result (with `data = [0.41, 0.96, 1.91, 2.9]` and `target = 7.75`):

```
>>> result
(0.96, 0.96, 2.9, 2.9)
>>> sum(result)
7.72
```

This approach might be very slow when `data` is a long list.

Comment: Yeah I guess that works, although seems indeed quite inefficient. Not just for long lists but also for small data elements. For example, `data, target = [0.01, 0.02], 10` takes me about 6 seconds.